# Recommended abstraction to transfer data over a nework than byte[] array?

Tags: java, design, serialization

I was curious, why do we prefer byte[] array to transfer data over the network and not anything else?

Or if I am missing anything, what are the other ways to transfer the data over a network.

Comment: Technically it's only sending bits over the network, not bytes, so a byte array is already an abstraction.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock Agree to your point. So while sending bits, can we use some other abstraction?

Comment: I mean yes, you could theoretically send any abstraction because at the lowest level they're just bits. It's just how the bits are encoded that gives meaning to the stream of zeroes and ones. You could send a stream of ints and then read them out as ASCII characters.

Comment: @n00b So when using the abstraction the performance will be effected, correct? If so, then what will be the best abstraction to use?

Comment: @ScottWhitlock I'm not sure, but I believe for most common network protocols (TCP, UDP, and everything built on them) the smallest unit of data is a byte, not a bit. There is an abstraction over bits alright, but it's several levels below the API that accepts a byte array.

Comment: @JNL who said using bytes is less performant than using bits? Yes it's an abstraction, but since when is processing data in chunks at a time rather than individual element as a time more or less performant? Chunking is a standard approach to processing data which improves performance for most scenarios and makes worse for some, depending on what exactly you're doing. Performance doesn't even begin to play into any of the abstractions you're referring to because eventually the bits need to become something useful, whether you write the abstraction or you use a standard one

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I would appreciate, if you could elaborate a little with some examples, like Abstraction preferred to be used for certain scenarios.

Comment: _"Why do we prefer byte[] array to transfer data over the network…?"_ -- What makes you think that "we" prefer that? FWIW, I don't. It seems you are thinking far too low-level. Take a look at the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). Why do I mention this? Because like with that model, you can build layers upon layers of increasingly abstract forms of communication (data structures) atop a `byte[]`. For example: **1.** First, a UTF8 character stream. Second, JSON syntax. Or: **2.** First, a UTF8 character stream. Second, XML syntax. Third, a SOAP message.

Comment: Because theoretically speaking we are sending *information* over the network, so it is natural to measure the transmission in  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat_(information), which is the natural unit for information entropy. <sarcasm>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do any other abstraction on top of the byte arrays, that's what serialization libraries do.

But to effectively communicate, both sides have to agree on the same (de)serialization format.  While there are several semi-standard ones (XML, JSON, MessagePack, Protocol Buffers), there's no *real* standard, so it's unlikely to include any one on the standard libraries, because it would be limited to only interoperate with Java programs at both ends.

Still, if you're writing both ends, it's easy to convene on any one.  I typically tend to JSON in most cases, and MessagePack when either time or space savings make up for the lower readability and interoperability.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, at the root level it's always bytes being sent. That's just how computers work. Each character that you're reading in this reply is a series of bytes encoded using the UTF-32 format (or, maybe it's another - I didn't code this site).

There are usually many libraries that will offer you forms of abstraction to sending blocks of bytes. The most popular is, tada, HTTP, or HyperText Transfer Protocol. Even when someone's not viewing a webpage, many network programmers like coding all communications as HTTP requests to simplify the request/response architecture, and make each block of information a (usually human-readable) string.

There are tiny tradeoffs in performance that are usually completely inconsequential - but high demand situations like video game networking or video calling will often take things back down to the root level and decide how each byte should be sent, in order to be most efficient.

Comment: So I believe "Performance" would be one major consideration for sendind data in bytes[]. I undersatand the system works in bytes, so that would be the fastest way.

Comment: UTF-8 is much more common on the web than UTF-32, and that's a good thing. For starters: UTF-32 is easily larger even if the content is primarily outside the BMP (as HTML etc. are still ASCII), and the ratio gets worse when it's primarily English text such as on this site.